# help in uniquely identifying combine columns

Tags: php, mysql

How can I uniquely identify two or more columns, that I have used table named address in the database, now address is has fields like street name, suite name and street num.

strnum   | strnam  |  sutname

---

1        | xyz     | 32

1        | xyz     | 32

now how can I uniquely these three columns. That is I want to check whether these three column are already inserted or not. If any field valus is changed than its ok, it will insert new one. but in case all three similar field..Help me to combinely identify these three fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `address` WHERE `strnum` = '$strnum' AND `strnam` = '$strnam' AND `sutname` = '$sutname' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    // If you get to here, there is no existing record
    $query = "INSERT INTO `address` (`strnum`,`strnam`,`sutname`) VALUES ('$strnum','$strnam','$sutname')";
    if (!mysql_query($query)) print('Insert failed!');
} else print('Record already exists!');
```

**EDIT** I just added a missing `;` so this parses...

Comment: This isn't the proper way to deal with relational databases. Just to anyone who might think this is how you check whether record exists and then to insert - don't do it. I'm not trying to bash on you Dave, and I'm not downvoting.

Comment: @N.B. I accept what your saying and no offence taken - I would be the first to admit I don't know everything. I take it that what you are doing is adding a `UNIQUE` multi-field index on all the fields you want to link? Does that not throw a duplicate key error when you try and do a duplicated insert?

Comment: yes, but if you use `INSERT IGNORE` then it won't error out and will ignore the data you want to insert. Alternatively, there's "INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statement that allows you to update the row whose unique key you hit.

Answer (score 2):

You do it by adding `unique` constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(strnum, strnam, sutname);
```

Then you do the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table (strnum, strnam, sutname) VALUES ('1', 'xyz', 'etc');
```

If the value exists already - no insert will happen and no errors will be raised (that's what the IGNORE part is).

By the way why do you use such short and vague column names? It's not the DOS era any more, you can be descriptive with your column names.

Comment: If I create or modify key uniquely without using simple single query is it same as above query...??

Comment: @Aditii - sorry but I don't understand what you mean. The example provided came with explanation, I think it's pretty much clear what it does, how and why. If not, well, then you need to read some mysql docs.

Comment: ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(strnum);
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(strnam);
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE(sutname);

is similar to above query...??

Answer (score 0):

just add them as unique keys in table structure and you'll not be able to insert two of them

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = $something AND col2 = $something2 AND col3 = $something3
```

(remember about escpaing php variables)
if the record is returned it means it exists. You can also add LIMIT 1 to make it faster.

if your question is about ENSURING that no duplicates occur in the table (for those 3 columns), then probably the best solution is to add UNIQUE index on those three columns.

Comment: how can I do this using php... That means I have 3 fields and three variables how can I check if values of these three variables are same in 3 columns of table or not...